# How can I build a game in Unity with minimum/no use of the visual editor?

Tags: c#, unity

I'd like to write a game completely in C#. In my search for an engine, I found Unity3D, but all the tutorials and documentation are speaking about a visual editor and the Unity IDE in which you click and point around to create scenes and scripts.

I don't want to do that. I prefer full code coverage over designers abstracting things away from me. I'd like to only write pure C# code from scratch or if required the Unity scripts as an addition. I couldn't find any explanation or documentation about doing so; how can I build a game using Unity and making minimum (or no) use of the visual editor?

Comment: Voting to close, this is a framework recommendation disguised as a question about Unity.

Comment: I'm not actually sure if I agree with that, though I wouldn't overturn a community close vote. However, I will note that this question is specifically asking about some capability of Unity: answers that don't address that may be removed. Let's *not* turn this into an off topic question if we don't have to, okay?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft yeah maybe the last sentence throws this discussion into the wrong direction, primarily i'd like to know if pure code is possible in Unity

Comment: Most developers look for a visual editor at some point to design their levels, because visually positioning stuff is so much simpler than setting the position of every little doodad in code. Same goes for editing/designing GUI layouts. Having this stuff already built-in is a huge benefit IMHO.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why exactly do you feel that the designer is abstracting away that most, if not all, middleware solutions do? Unity does a pretty good job of separating the designer from scripting environment (a little too well sometimes,  I'm sure most Unity users at one time or another come across something in the UnityEditor namespace they wish they could use at runtime).

Comment: @bummzack: I prefer writing my own level editor which provides only the stuff really neccessary for my game - and can be included or provided to end-users if I want to publish it with the game.

Comment: @AssortedTrailmix I'm very used to do everything by code. I'd not only have to learn about the Unity API, I'd also have to learn how to use the editor and where to do this and that. Maybe it doesn't even do things in a way I would do it in a self-made editor / designer. Another reason is stated in my comment response for bummzack. On another side note is written that I probably have a fear towards designers since I had to use the WinForms designer very often which sucks :P

Comment: Well Unity is middleware built on middleware. It doesn't much that isn't applicable elsewhere (for example, physics built with PhysX). And the editor doesn't play a very large role in development, it's mostly positioning objects, and even then it's not forcing you to do that, you can always instantiate objects at run time and only use GameObjects as placeholders for your code. And a runtime editor should be implemented in the higher levels of a game than right above the internals of the engine anyways in my opinion.

Comment: Also I'd say a strict aversion to visual editors isn't not a very "scalable" approach to game development. It's nice to be able to write a game "bare metal", but it's also a lot of work to reproduce, especially since it's already been done in proven products. There's this sweet spot where you either have a lot of time, or you have a large team (and budget) and specific requirements that enable you "roll your own", that's why embracing middleware like Unity is so important.

Comment: `I prefer writing my own level editor which provides only the stuff really neccessary for my game` okay that basically means you don't want to be using a game engine, you want to be programming with a graphics library. However you already hit a technical snag when trying to do that, so... I sense a contradiction here.

Comment: @JoshPetrie I'm not so sure we're asking about a capability of Unity here. There's a trivial answer that is simply "Yes" because you can create a 'main' object in the scene and then do everything else from code. That's not a useful question or answer. It's like saying "I don't like using the letter E, can I code without it?" to which the answer is "yes, because it's **code**, you can do anything in code. But why would you want to?" Once you're past the trivial answer this question only goes to opinion-based answers as to whether or not avoiding the editor is a good thing or not..

Comment: @jhocking Then our defintion of game engine seems to be very different. A class library is a game engine if it abstracts typical game tasks like camera mathematics, a sound system and maybe even a bit of physics stuff, but a designer isn't a requirement and in my opinion shouldn't even be a must-use.

Comment: @MrCranky Fair points; I have made some edits to the question to focus it instead on the "how," and removing some of the answers that no longer fit that bill.

Comment: While my answer addresses the question here ("can I build build a game with minimal use of the visual editor") it sounds like you really ought to keep working with SharpDX and figure out your camera control issue. I'm not sure why you have such disdain for designers; as you get more experienced in game development, you'll find that you really want to create tools that let *them* build as much of the game as possible, leaving you free to address more core technical issues, like the networking or whatever.

Comment: related tangent: thank god for xml/json. I write code that reads in and responds to data files, and *someone else* handles all the work of filling out those data files.

Comment: absolutely true, but _i_ would like to be that _someone_ while the engine only assists me through basic game tasks

Comment: Unity is editor-centric. It is their philosophy if you could say that. I think you should either reconsider your choice of engine or you should understand the power of the editor. "thank god for xml/json" this implies a misunderstanding of Unity's prefab system. Let's say you have 100 different units in an RTS game. You require only 1 class for this. The "json" is your prefab setup which you can fill out however you want. I think what you are looking for is a 'framework' like LibGDX instead of a game engine.

Comment: I think you might almost be able to make a game without the Unity editor, but it would have way less features, and I have no idea why you *would* want to make a game without Unity editor anyway.

Comment: The idea of using a system for this that relies on an editor is ill-conceived. Not to mention you're still bound by their licenses. You're just shooting yourself in the foot by not using the editor. Why not just use something like ogre3d or something? http://wiki.ogre3d.org/MOGRE

Comment: I write a bit about how to use pure C# https://codeburst.io/making-unity-games-in-pure-c-2b1723cdc71f

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I am a complete beginner in Unity, but this is how I do it at the moment, and it reduces the editor usage to minimum:

In editor, I only have three objects: An empty GameObject called "main", a camera, and a light. And this is only because so far I only work with a single camera and a single light, so it was faster this way. Later I will probably remove them, and only the "main" will remain.

In "Assets/MyScripts" I have a class "Main", which is added to the "main" GameObject as a behavior. Which means that when the program starts, the "Main" class in instantiated and its method is called. The "Main" class is like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start ()
    {
        // initialize the game
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        // update physics
    }

}
```

In the game I dynamically build the environment like this:

```
GameObject floor = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (PrimitiveType.Cube);
floor.renderer.material.color = RandomGreen ();
```

But this is because so far I am only making a prototype. Later I will want to replace the cubes with some nice things edited in Blender. Which will require making them in Blender, and importing them to Units as "prefabs". Then, I will similarly instantiate the "prefabs" from the C# code.

If you want to make an object react to events, such as collisions with other objects, you can instantiate the object and add them dynamically a behavior class, which is a C# class derived from MonoBehavior. For example, if you want to have a car, you make a car prefab, and write a "CarBehavior" class for its behavior in the game.

This way you can reduce the interaction with the editor to a minimum, although probably not completely to zero. Now it depends on whether this is an acceptable solution for you.

Comment: I'd say this looks like a pretty clear and solid answer for just a Unity beginner :)

Comment: Thanks! I am an experienced programmer otherwise, but this is my first project in Unity and it is far from finished. I haven't used prefabs yet. There may be some complications I am currently not aware of, so I recommend taking my advice with a grain of salt.

By the way, [serialization in Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) feels a bit counter-intuitive to me. I will have to study it deeper, and it may influence some design decisions.

Answer (score 9):

When working with Unity you have to do some work within Unity's editor; that's simply how Unity works.

However the *vast* majority of what you'd be doing as a programmer doesn't happen within Unity's editor; the script files are external text files written in an external IDE, and as a programmer you only use Unity's editor for linking which scripts to run and then hitting Play to actually run the game. That's not unlike linking in classes in the project settings, and then hitting Run within your IDE.

Most other game development tools that have a central visual editor are also saddled with limited and inflexible scripting support, but Unity doesn't suffer that disadvantage. Although everything created for Unity ultimately goes through the visual editor, this core interface involves a lot of linking projects to custom code that runs in Unity's game engine. Experienced programmers, don't dismiss this development environment, mistaking it for some click together game creator with limited programming capability!

(also, it sounds like the book I'm currently writing would be a great resource for you, since it's targeted at experienced programmers)

Comment: was in the middle of reading your book when i came across this answer

Answer (score 7):

I believe what you are looking for is the [Futile Framework](https://github.com/MattRix/Futile) for Unity.

Basically, you can then do all your programming using scripts without having to "drag and drop" stuff or mess with the visual editor much. All you need is a single GameObject in your Scene which will be the container for your entire game.
You then do everything procedurally as you would with a non-visual editor.

Disclaimer: While Futile is very code centric, it is inevitable that you will have to mess with the Unity editor in some fashion. But this is very much reduced with Futile.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to all the good answers here, especially @jhocking 's answer:

Almost everything I have found in Unity has a plain text counterpart in the projects folder tree. I have directly edited prefabs and other gameObjects without opening Unity, and those changes were successfully found by other devs upon commit.

While I didnt know as much about the Futile Framework until today, it looks to be a really awesome way to get at everything.

I currently use all the drag-and-drop stuff instead of going script-based, but that will have to change since my goal will have procedurally generated levels and bad guys.

My two cents says basically get the few objects you need in Unity, then rely on scripts in an external editor. You can do nearly everything in plain text.